# Android AlertDialogs are not showing buttons in specific acitivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want to show a basic Alert Dialog with Yes No options, but none of the methods seems to work. **The dialog is shown but the YES NO buttons no** I am working with API 26.
I am showing Alert Dialog in another activity with no problem (None of them are the main activity), even with custom layouts.

I am using many Alerts dialogs, but there is an example for go back confirmation.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.goBackAlert))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        ScanRouteActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(_no, null)
                .show();
    }
```

This function is working fine in another activity.

I've also tried something like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.goBackAlert));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                QuarantineActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(_no, null);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

AND

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.goBackAlert))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        QuarantineActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(_no, null);
        final AlertDialog ad  = builder.create();
        ad.show();
```

I've already try the followings AlertDialog imports:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
```

This are the XML for the Activities
**In this activity is working fine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".ScanRouteActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVIdRoute"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TitleFont"
        android:text=""/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/menuLabels"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtVCurrentContent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frmScanContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**HERE IS NOT WORKING**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".QuarantineActivity">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select container type:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinQType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/containerType_list"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/add_photo"
            android:id="@+id/btnAddPhoto"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/circleBtnDark"/>
    </TableRow>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frmQuarantine"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgVPhoto"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat = "@drawable/no_image"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just call `onBackPressed()` what's with all the activity referencing.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not my question, I call that function because I need go back confirmation.
It is just an example, the AlertDialog is not working in any function.

Comment: Which theme is the dialog not working activity using?

Comment: The default theme, the only thing I changed is the background color and it is the same in both activities.

Comment: make sure that the onBackPressed method is called in the activities where the dialog is not showing

Comment: I made a mistake writing the question.
The dialog is shown but the buttons are not.

Comment: Do you have the same `AlertDialog` class imported in both Activities? Are both Activities extending the same class; e.g., `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, i am using
```import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to implement a whole class and XML layout to manage AlertDialgs and after that I have not have issues with that, the bright side is that I had the opportunity to customize my AlertDialogs.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay,** 
**Please try**

```
<ImageView
       ...
        android:src= "@drawable/no_image"/>
```

**in your XML instead of**

```
<ImageView
           ...
            app:srcCompat = "@drawable/no_image"/>
```

**GOODLUCK Bro**

Comment: Thank you, I did it but nothing happen, how is that suppose to work and what is the relation with AlertDialog?

Comment: The relationship not only with the AlertDialog, sometimes Android needs some Libs to understand `app:srcCompat`